# jQuery Cycle: How to change transition effect on a running slideshow

Tags: jquery, cycle, transition, effect

i'm using the `before:` option of the jQuery Cycle plugin to determine whether the user is moving to the left or right through the slideshow, and i'd like to animate accordingly (scrollLeft, scrollRight).

Unfortunately, I cannot find how to alter the plugin's options (the transition effect) while it's running.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like this is the effect that you want: http://jsfiddle.net/zvVcD/

If that's the case, you just need to use the "scrollHorz" effect, and then define previous and next triggers, like so:

```
$('#s2').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz',
    speed: 'fast',
    timeout: 0,
    next: '#next2',
    prev: '#prev2'
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This indeed solves this particular issue. But do you have any idea for a more general approach, for any other effects? For example: fade on next, slide on previous.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think the Cycle plugin supports what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the more general approach:

```
var $cycler = $( ".cycler" ),
    prev = function() { $cycler.cycle( prevIndex, "scrollRight" ); },
    next = function() { $cycler.cycle( nextIndex, "scrollLeft" ); };

    $cycler.cycle({
                     fx:     'scrollLeft',
                     after: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options) {
                             slideIndex = options.currSlide;
                             nextIndex = slideIndex + 1;
                             prevIndex = slideIndex -1;

                             if (slideIndex == options.slideCount-1) {
                                 nextIndex = 0;
                             }

                             if (slideIndex == 0) {
                                 prevIndex = options.slideCount-1;
                             }
                         }
                 });

    $( ".prev" ).bind( "click", prev );
    $( ".next" ).bind( "click", next );
```

You can change `scrollLeft` and `scrollRight` into whatever you like. Note that I'm using `.prev`, `.next` and `.cycler` classes for my previous button, next button and cycler container respectively.

Comment: Hi, i didn't try it yet, but it definitely looks very interesting. Thanks!